# Ubuntu 12.04 booting into busybox after update

Tags: 12.04, boot, kernel, boot-repair, busybox

Every time the system updates the kernel from 3.5.0-24 to 3.5.0-34 I get dropped into a busybox prompt at boot, but I can boot just fine using the previous kernel. I've tried all I know. I did a `fsck.ext3 -f /dev/sdb2` using the alternate install CD. I've used boot-repair but to avail, I've checked for bad blocks but there are none. Should I purge the new kernel and use the old one instead? This is the output from boot-repair the first time, no purge. http://paste.ubuntu.com/5809230/

Comment: Do you have enough disk space? Purge the new kernel and reinstall it, and if it shows any error message include it in your question. Also, you can try kernel 3.8.0: `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-raring`.

Comment: @EricCarvalho I have more than enough disk space, I have almost 460GB left of 500GB. And there are no error messages, it just fails silently. I will try using the 3.8 kernel.

Comment: I installed the 3.8.0 kernel, but it failed on boot dropping me back into busybox. Just did a boot-repair, without purging the kernels. http://paste.ubuntu.com/5809521/ Going to reboot, and see if it works now.

Comment: 3.8.0 didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it, using boot-repair, I added the kernel option `rootdelay=90`. Now the linux-kernel-3.5.0-34-generic-image. But after much research and testing, I have decided to go with the linux-generic image boots properly. which is kernel version 3.2.0-48. It's the only one that boots up correctly without having to add any kernel options. Also using this kernel solved another issue I had, which was a waking up took too long. Now waking up after suspend takes just 2 seconds as opposed to 10-20 seconds using the other images.

Comment: Good job. I strongly recommend you report the bug (and the workaround you found) to the kernel developers. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs

Comment: Sure things, will do.